# PyRun_SimpleFile in C++ (Visual Studio Desktop application) does not call Python file (No error)

Tags: c++, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I hope I am not duplicating posts from the past (although I have read and tried many existing posts in stackoverflow without any gain). I have a VC++ application where I am trying to call a function that would then run a Python file. I have Python 311 installed and configured via the project settings. The code compiles fine but I believe does not run the file encode_post.py. The returned value from PyRun_SimpleFile is 0 (if I run another file the result is -1). In the encode_post.py file, I am simply opening a test.txt file and appending the command line argument argv[1] "Hello world" (I tried without providing the argument too). If I double click encode_post.py in the folder or run it via the command prompt, it runs fine and writes the line in test.txt, but running the file via C++ does not append anything. Below is my code which does not throw any error or breaks the application. In project settings, I also configured to run Debug DLL in runtime library in code generation. Any advice would be great as at this point I am not sure where exactly the issue is arising. I also have #include <Python.h> in my code without any error

```
char* argv[2];
argv[0] = "encode_post.py";
argv[1] = "Hello world";


try {
    
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_SetProgramName((wchar_t*)argv[0]);
    PySys_SetArgv(2, (wchar_t**)argv);
    file = fopen(argv[0], "r");
    if (file) {
        int result = PyRun_SimpleFile(file, argv[0]);
        fclose(file);
    }
    Py_Finalize();
        
    
    
}
catch (IOException^ ex) {
    // Could not open the file
}
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use _Py_fopen_obj. The snippet below works for me.

```
PyObject* obj = Py_BuildValue("s", argv[0]);
FILE* file = _Py_fopen_obj(obj, "r");
if (file) {
    PyRun_SimpleFile(file, argv[0]);
}
```